# Objects vanishing when clicked on / objects not moving towards mouse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here's my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GoToMouse : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Transform tf;
    private bool Selected = false;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        tf = GetComponent<Transform>();
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if (Selected == false)
        {
            Selected = true;
        }
        if (Selected == true)
        {
            Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            tf.position = mousePos;
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        if (Selected == true)
        {
            Selected = false;
        }
        if (Selected == false)
        {

        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {


        
    }
}
```

In this script, I want to do two things. I want an object to become selected when clicked and unselected when you let go of the mouse. When an object is selected I want it to move towards the mouse cursor. Basically, you can drag it around with the mouse cursor and throw it with physics.

This script has a couple problems.

1. Whenever I click the object it completely vanishes. I have no background or anything it could be going behind, so I don't know what is causing this. The object also doesn't move anywhere (I checked its transform) So it appears it's sprite just stops rendering
2. Whenever I select it and try to move it, it moves less that 1 unit along the X and Y axis and then stops. For some reason, it deselects itself or stops moving before I let go of the mouse. I don't know why this would be since the only way to deselect an object is by letting go of the mouse.

This is a unity2D project BTW, and this script is the backbone of the game I'm making. Please help!

thanks.

Comment: your if checks are quite redundant ... your `OnMouseUp` actually does nothing ... and note that there already is the built-in property `transform` .. you shouldn't use `GetComponent<Transform>`

Answer (score 0):

I understand tf as a character which is needed to move.

According to the OnMouseDown function,

> OnMouseDown is called when the user has pressed the mouse button while over the Collider.

[Doc Link here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html)

You will require a background and script may attach to it. Get the mouse position from background. Than set the position to the tf(character). 2D game z position always should be 0.
And of course, you can change the size of the background as large as you need.

Image and script can explain better.

[image]

Here is GoToMouse.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GoToMouse : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform tf;
    private bool Selected = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // the tf is drag and drop from unity
        //tf = GetComponent<Transform>();
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if (Selected == false)
        {
            Selected = true;
        }
        if (Selected == true)
        {
            Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            tf.position = new Vector3(mousePos.x,mousePos.y,tf.position.z); // notice the tf.position.z
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        if (Selected == true)
        {
            Selected = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out, I'm not sure what I was doing wrong but this new script seems to work great. Here's the script for people who want to plagiarize.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveTowards : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float force = 1f;
    private bool selected = false;

    public void Awake()
    {
        //Get rigidbody from the gameobject this script is attatched to
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        //become selected when clicked
        selected = true;
    }

    public void OnMouseUp()
    {
        //become deselected when you let go of left click
        selected = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (selected == true)
        {
            //move towards mouse if selected
            Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            Vector3 dir = (mousePos - transform.position);
            dir.z = 0.0f;
            Vector3 dirNormalized = dir.normalized;
            Vector2 relativePos = mousePos - gameObject.transform.position;
            rb.AddForce(relativePos * force);
            
        }

    }

}
```